Prove that $\frac{X_{(1)}+X_{(n)}}{2}$ is minimax for $\theta$ when $X_i\sim U(\theta-\frac{1}{2},\theta+\frac{1}{2})$
Let $(X_1,..., X_n)$ be a random sample from the uniform distribution on the interval $U(\theta-\frac{1}{2},\theta+\frac{1}{2})$ with an unknown $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$. Under the squared error loss, show that $\frac{X_{(1)}+X_{(n)}}{2}$ is the unique minimax estimator of $\theta$, where $X_{(j)}$ is the j-th order statistic.
This problem is from Jun Shao's book (#4.78), but the answer uses the fact that the  Pitman estimator is admissible, which I think is too hard for me. May I ask if there's other easier way (like, use some prior to make the risk constant) to prove that $\frac{X_{(1)}+X_{(n)}}{2}$ is minimax/admissible? Thanks!

Probably better to ask this on https://stats.stackexchange.com.
